# Wall Jump Movement Problem Unity3D Time.deltatime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

trying to make a wall jump in my game. with the current script my player does'nt move at all. if i remove the multiply by Time.deltatime the player is moving but in teleport. how can i make the player move smoothly?
Would appreciate help, thanks.

```
 [SerializeField] float slideForce = 3f;
 
        [SerializeField] float wallJumpHeight = 3f;
        [SerializeField] float wallJumpRange = 3f;
        [SerializeField] float wallJumpGravity = 9.8f;
        Vector3 horizontalMovement;
        bool doWallJump = false;
       
        private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
        {
            if (hit.normal.y < 0.3f)
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal, Color.red, 1.25f);
         
 
                if ((Keyboard.current.spaceKey.isPressed || (Gamepad.current != null && Gamepad.current.buttonSouth.isPressed )))
                {
                    horizontalMovement = hit.normal;
                    Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal, Color.yellow, 1.25f);
                    _controller.enabled = true;
 
                    doWallJump = true;
                   
                    float verticalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(wallJumpHeight * wallJumpRange * wallJumpGravity);
             
             
             
                    _controller.Move(horizontalMovement.normalized * Time.deltaTime +
                     new Vector3(0.0f, verticalVelocity, 0.0f)* Time.deltaTime);
 
                }
            }
        }
```

Without Time.deltatime works but with teleport

```
_controller.Move(horizontalMovement.normalized *  +
                     new Vector3(0.0f, verticalVelocity, 0.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is `CharacterController` doesn't have a `velocity` like the `Rigidbody`.

If you want to apply a certain movement over a range of time you need to iterate each frame and apply according resulting movement.

Currently your `Move` is only called exactly **once** - either with the entire forces - jumps - or with the velocity (after applying `Time.deltaTime`) but only for a single frame -> barely moves at all.

```
    [SerializeField] float slideForce = 3f;

    [SerializeField] float wallJumpHeight = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float wallJumpRange = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float wallJumpGravity = 9.8f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpDuration = 2f;

    bool doWallJump = false;
   
    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if (hit.normal.y < 0.3f)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal, Color.red, 1.25f);
     

            if ((Keyboard.current.spaceKey.isPressed || (Gamepad.current != null && Gamepad.current.buttonSouth.isPressed)))
            {
                var horizontalMovement = hit.normal;
                Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal, Color.yellow, 1.25f);
                _controller.enabled = true;

                doWallJump = true;
               
                float verticalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(wallJumpHeight * wallJumpRange * wallJumpGravity);
         
                if(currentJumpRoutine!= null) StopCoroutine(currentJumpRoutine);
                currentJumpRoutine = StartCoroutine(ApplyJumpOverTime(horizontalMovement, verticalVelocity, jumpDuration));
            }
        }
    }
    
    private IEnuermator ApplyJumpOverTime(Vector3 horizontalMovement, float verticalVelocity, float jumpDuration)
    {
        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < jumpDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            _controller.Move((horizontalMovement.normalized + new Vector3(0.0f, verticalVelocity, 0.0f)) * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        currentJumpRoutine = null;
    }
```

usually you would have all user input in a single script and locally store an overall applied `movement` vector where you than apply the user input and gravity etc to. Then in `Update` (-> every frame) you apply that `movement` to the `CharacterController.Move`

Comment: Now i get it, thank you so much!